# How can I interact with ArcObjects from a windows service?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-engine

How can I interact with ArcObjects from a windows service?  It appears that I can't work with an AxMapControl object from a console or service, because it complains about the activeX state.  How does one interact with ArcObjects from a service?

Comment: What is it about the mapcontrol you need to use in a non-interactive process that can't be done using just a plain IMap?

Comment: Well, I want to create some ILocator objects (so I need to get a layer, and call a few functions) and then I will send address data to this service, and it will return lat / longs back, maybe I can do that with an IMap, I will look into it.

Comment: Your service could use IMapDocument to get the layer.